# How to catch multiple events from a single function in the hardhat framework?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, events, hardhat, unittesting

I was going through a function that emits multiple events. Usualyy, if a function emits a single event, we can check that during the test cases using:

```
 await expect(contract.claimTokens(busd.address))
   .to.emit(contract, "Claimed")
   .withArgs(user.address, busd.address);
```

But what if a function has more than 1 event? How to compare that? Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer. You just have to append the next event in the same `expect`. Something like this:

```
await expect(contract.claimTokens(busd.address))
   .to.emit(contract, "Claimed")
   .withArgs(user.address, busd.address)
   .to.emit(contract, "Claimed")
   .withArgs(user.address, busd.address);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it didn't work. The event expected first wasn't correctly tested, I can put any value, and it returns always true.

I change it like this:

```
            const tx = contract.claimTokens(busd.address);
            await Promise.all([
                expect(tx).to.emit(contract, "Claimed").withArgs(user.address, busd.address),
                expect(tx).to.emit(contract, "Claimed").withArgs(user.address, busd.address)
            ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .and infront to make it more readable

```
await expect(contract.claimTokens(busd.address))
   .to.emit(contract, "Claimed")
   .withArgs(user.address, busd.address)
   .and.to.emit(contract, "Claimed")
   .withArgs(user.address, busd.address);
```